# C# MS Unit test keep setting output type to console app. causing "No Main Method"

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I got this Error

> " Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS5001  Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable
> for an entry
> point TestNinja   C:\Users\NAV\source\repos\MultipleProjs\TestNinja\CSC   1   Active

If i right click project and go to properties i see project is set outputType  'Console Application"  If try to change it to class library i can't d it.
How to fix this. I didn't have this broble with Unit Test project in .net Framework. But when I switched to .net core the complications started. its happening in both MSTest and xUnit Test projects.

Comment: A dll and an exe are basically the same file but the dll does not have a main method.  To run an app in Windows you need a main entry point and the dll does not have the main.  The simplest solution is to create a console application with one instruction that calls the dll.